# Is it possible to upgrade to an IAP item with the same subscription duration in the same subscription group?

Tags: in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

I have 4 items in an IAP subscription group :
auto-renewable monthly subcription - X USD
auto-renewable yearly subscription - Y USD
auto-renewable monthly subscription with 2 week trial period - X USD
auto-renewable yearly subscription with 2 week trial period - Y USD

My app currently shows the first two items :
auto-renewable monthly subcription - X USD
auto-renewable yearly subscription - Y USD

I am planning to push out an update of the app that shows the second two items :
auto-renewable monthly subscription with 2 week trial period - X USD
auto-renewable yearly subscription with 2 week trial period - Y USD

I already have users who subscribed to one of the first two items ( the non-trial ones ).
What happens when they install the updated app, and trying to purchase the two new items ( "auto-renewable monthly subscription with 2 week trial period - X USD" and "auto-renewable yearly subscription with 2 week trial period - Y USD") ?

Does the App Store show them this dialog :

```
You're currently subscribed to this.
Your <period> subscription renews on <date> for <price>. To review subscription settings or cancel this subscription, tap Manage.
Manage | OK
```

or this one :

```
Confirm Purchase
Do you want to modify your subscription to Pro Subscription for <period> at <price>? Your new subscription will begin and you'll be charged when your current subscription expires on <date>.
Cancel | Continue
```

or something else?

I want to make sure that our users won't be charged twice for two subscriptions that are overlapping.
Does having them in the same subscription group guarantees it?

I want to make sure that our users won't be able to purchase the old subscription (the non-trial one) any more.
How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A user cannot purchase two subscriptions in the same group at the same time, so as long as all 4 subscriptions are in the same group, you won't have any problems.

However, users who have already purchased a non-trial subscription will not be able to convert to the trial version and receive a trial as trials cannot be completed once a real purchase has been made.

I would also suggest making sure the purchasing UI isn't visible if a user has an active subscription, this will save your users confusion and probably save you some customer service work.

Comment: Thanks for your response! :)

Comment: I have one more question : 
I would like to : 
1.: keep offering the ability to purchase the old (non-trial) subscription type in the current live version of the app
2.: but I wouldn't like to let our users to modify their subscription from the trial subscription to the non-trial one via the subscription management page ( https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions )
3.: and keep the current (non-trial) subscriptions alive
4.: the trial subscription must have a different price than the non-trial one
How can I achieve this?